# Get content of a mail IMAPCLIENT

Tags: python, imapclient

I am using the IMAPclient to get the content of emails, so i made this piece of code :

```
messages = server.search(['FROM', user['email']], charset='UTF-8')
if len(messages) > 0:
    for mail_id, data in server.fetch(messages, ['ENVELOPE']).items():
        envelope = data[b'ENVELOPE']
```

How can I have the content of the emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if you found the answer elsewhere... try:

```
   messages = server.search(['FROM', user['email']], charset='UTF-8')
   if len(messages) > 0:
       for mail_id, data in server.fetch(messages,['ENVELOPE','BODY[TEXT]']).items():
           envelope = data[b'ENVELOPE']
           body = data[b'BODY[TEXT]']
```

The email content is in body.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I did like that :)

Comment: how about listing email attachments please ?